# form not submitting data to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to let the user update recipe info. When i hit submit it goes back to the recipes page but the info was not changed. basically i have no idea why the database is not being updated, i get no errors to help me figure it out either.
any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
here is my controller:

```
public function update(){
            $data = array(
                'id'  => $this->input->post('recipe_id'),
                'title' => $this->input->post('recipe_name'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('recipe_description'),
                'stars' => $this->input->post('rating'),
                'directions' => $this->input->post('recipe_directions'),
                'link' => $this->input->post('recipe_link'),
                'genre' => $this->input->post('recipe_genre'),
                'posted' =>  date('Y-m-d')
            );
            $this->recipe_model->update_recipe($data);
            $this->recipes();
        }
```

here is my Model:

```
function update_recipe($data){
      $id = $data['id'];
      unset($data['id']);
      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->update('recipes' ,$data);
      return true;
    }
```

Here is my view

```
<?php 
    $attributes = array('id' => 'update-recipe-form');
    echo form_open('addRecipe/update', $attributes); ?>
    <input type="text" name="recipe_id" class="hide" value="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>">
    <fieldset class="name">
        <legend>Name of recipe</legend>
        <input type="text" name="recipe_name" class="recipe_name" placeholder="<?php echo $recipe_title; ?>" value="<?php echo $recipe_title; ?>" tabindex="1">
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: i realize the $id is not being passed over to the model when i submit the form array. i just don't understand why it is not. I feel like i have everytihng in order logically.

Comment: Could you post the HTML of your form?

Comment: Edit the question and Show us your form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass data directly to Models, you pass data to Controllers that use models to do something.

```
class addRecipe extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model( 'my_model' );
        $this->load->helper( 'form' );
    }

    function index() // The default view
    {
        $data_to_pass = array(
            /* All the variables to pass to the view.
             * This is what the form "preloads" when loaded the first time
             */
            'recipe_title' => 'somevalue',
            'recipe_description' => 'somevalue',
            // etc...
        );
        $this->load->view( 'view_name', $data_to_pass );
    }

    function update()
    {
        // Do something with the data, use model methods, print it, etc.
        // $this->my_model->do_something();
        $id = $this->input->post('recipe_id');

        $data = array(
            'title'       => $this->input->post('recipe_name'), // Title or Name here?
            'description' => $this->input->post('recipe_description'),
            'stars'       => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'directions'  => $this->input->post('recipe_directions'),
            'link'        => $this->input->post('recipe_link'),
            'genre'       => $this->input->post('recipe_genre'),
            'posted'      => date('Y-m-d')
        );

        $success = $this->recipe_model->update_recipe( $id, $data );

        if ( $success )
            $this->load->view( /* your success view */ );
        else
        {
            // Something went wrong
            echo 'MySQL error message: ' . $this->db->_error_message();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Your model:

```
class Recipe_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database(); // If it's not auto-loaded
    }

    function update_recipe( $id, $data )
    {
        $this->db->where( 'id', $id );
        $this->db->update( 'recipes', $data );

        return ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ); // False if no recipes were modified
    }
}
```

And your form:

```
<?=form_open('addRecipe/update', array( 'id' => 'update-recipe-form' ) ); ?>
    <?php
        // Will produce <input type="hidden" name="hidden_variable" value="hidden_value" />
        echo form_hidden('hidden_variable', 'hidden_value');
    ?>

    <fieldset class="name">
        <legend>Name of recipe</legend>
        <input type="text" name="recipe_name" placeholder="<?=$recipe_title; ?>" value="<?=$recipe_title; ?>" tabindex="1">
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Add all other required fields... -->

    <?php
        // Will produce <input type="submit" name="submit_button_name" value="Update recipe" />
        echo form_submit( 'submit_button_name', 'Update recipe' );
    ?>
<?=form_close(); ?>
```

You can get more info about the form helper here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: I already have the 'id' of the item I want to edit. So i created a input and echo'd out the 'id' in the value field. the user does not need to see this i just wanted to pass the id value so i can edit the correct item with the unique id number.<input type="text" name="recipe_id" class="hide" value="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>" >

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller I just modified the answer, see if it helps.